# Refactor IF ... ELSE desing

Tags: c#, design-patterns, architecture

I have legacy code and my task to refactor it.

1. There is base class (ie **vehicle**)
2. it's heirs (**car, bus, motorcycle** and so on)
3. **Service** that has to choose and greate instance appropriate heir by parameter

So I've something like this:

...

```
   if (param == "car")
        result = new Car();
    else if (sectionType == "bus")
        result = new Bus();
    else if (sectionType == "motorcycle")
        result = new Motorcycle();
```

...

I think that code **isn't productive and supported**.

**Q:** My aim is founding out the better design solution.

Thx in advance

Comment: Using interfaces could be a choice....

Comment: But i how it helps me. I found out how to rewrite current implementation in more clear way. thanks for your attention

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it´s a review and thus should go to https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Every question with attached code example can be considered as review. I think it's common problem and there is some " pattern" to resolve such kind of problems

Comment: @AllmanTool but you're not looking to fix a specific problem, you're just looking for guidance on how best to approach a general problem, but with a specific code snippet.  So that's not really the point of *this* site.

Comment: _"Every question with attached code example can be considered as review."_ That's incorrect. Questions with _working_ code seeking improvement are review. Questions with Code that doesn't work or doesn't result in expected output is a different story.

Comment: When i took appropriate hash tags for this question i had found "design patterns" and "architecture". So i would like resolve my concrete desing pattern issue ( code above). what's wrong?

Comment: I'm curious about legacy code with vehicle classes. It's the classic *textbook example* (opposite of legacy in the real world).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have there is a factory, so you could encapsulate the logic in a factory class to keep it cleaner and more maintainable.

If the factory class knows all the types that it needs to create, then it can be responsible for all the constructors. However, if one or more vehicle classes are unknown to it, you can provide it with some kind of registration method so that other code could add more constructors to it.

Here's an example. Let's suppose that we have:

```
public abstract class Vehicle {}
public class Car : Vehicle {}
public class Bus : Vehicle {}
```

Then you can write a factory like this:

```
public sealed class VehicleFactory
{
    public VehicleFactory()
    {
        RegisterConstructor("car", () => new Car());
        RegisterConstructor("bus", () => new Bus());
    }

    public void RegisterConstructor(string name, Func<Vehicle> func)
    {
        _map.Add(name, func);
    }

    public Vehicle Create(string name)
    {
        if (_map.TryGetValue(name, out Func<Vehicle> create))
            return create();

        throw new InvalidOperationException($"No such vehicle name: {name}");
    }

    readonly Dictionary<string, Func<Vehicle>> _map = new Dictionary<string, Func<Vehicle>>();
}
```

Now suppose that you want to support an additional type, `Motorcycle`, that the factory doesn't know about. You can still handle that by having other code call `RegisterConstructor()` to add it, like so:

```
class Motorcycle : Vehicle { }

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var factory = new VehicleFactory();
        factory.RegisterConstructor("motorcycle", () => new Motorcycle());

        var bike = factory.Create("motorcycle");
        var car  = factory.Create("car");
    }
}
```

Note that in real code, you are may want to abstract the concrete classes into abstract base classes or interfaces, but for this example it's simpler to just use concrete classes.

Also, ideally you would want to use dependency injection via a `VehicleFactory` constructor rather than using a `RegisterConstructor()` method:

```
public sealed class VehicleFactory
{
    public VehicleFactory(params (string name, Func<Vehicle> constructor)[] constructors)
    {
        _map.Add("car", () => new Car());
        _map.Add("bus", () => new Bus());

        foreach (var c in constructors)
        {
            _map.Add(c.name, c.constructor);
        }
    }

    public Vehicle Create(string name)
    {
        if (_map.TryGetValue(name, out Func<Vehicle> create))
            return create();

        throw new InvalidOperationException($"No such vehicle name: {name}");
    }

    readonly Dictionary<string, Func<Vehicle>> _map = new Dictionary<string, Func<Vehicle>>();
}
```

Which you could use like this:

```
class Motorcycle : Vehicle {}
class MilkFloat : Vehicle  {}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var factory = new VehicleFactory(
            ("motorcycle", () => new Motorcycle()),
            ("milk float", () => new MilkFloat())
        );

        var bike = factory.Create("motorcycle");
        var car  = factory.Create("car");
        var milk = factory.Create("milk float");
    }
}
```